# regular expression: not containing string

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I have two strings :

string1: `platform1-05_02_00.001:platform`
string2: `platform1-domino-05_02_00.001:platform`

in the first one, the version (`05_02_00.001`) is to be changed, at first I tried the regular expression:

```
sed -i 's/platform1-.*:platform/platform1-06:hybrisb/g' file
```

but it changes the 2 strings.
That's why i'm looking for some regex to tell the sed to look for the string where the isn't "domino" (not containing domino)

Comment: If any of the existing answers solves your problem, please consider accepting it via the checkmark. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

One way to do it:

```
sed '/domino/! s/platform1-.*:platform/platform1-06:hybrisb/g' file
```

`/domino/!` selects lines that don't match `domino`.

Comment: this solution works only if the the 2 strings were on seperate lines which is not my case

Comment: @mohamedwaelthabet You might find it less embarrassing to try out your claim before posting.

Comment: this was very useful, since regex negation `[^x]` considered caret as movement backwards in current line instead.

Answer (score 1):

Consider skipping lines that contain "platform-domino" with the `n` command:

```
sed '/platform1-domino/ n; s/platform1-.*:platform/platform1-06:hybrisb/g' file
```

Or, search and replace, but eliminating the letters as possibilities for the match:

```
sed 's/platform1-[^d][^o][^m][^i][^n][^o].*:platform/platform1-06:hybrisb/g' file
```